# 一つの web サーバーに複数のサイトが含まれる場合、/var/www 以下のディレクトリの構成はどうなりますか？

Tags: linux

ウエブサイト・ウエブアプリを **/var/www** の下に置いた方が良いと言われていますが、見つけた例の中には **/var/www/html/** ぐらいしかありませんでした。仮に一つのサーバは複数のウエブサイト・アプリ（例えば、example.com、yourtube.com、headbook.com）を含めているとしら、 **/var/www** 以下構造はどうなりますでしょうか？

論理上は以下のようであるべきでしょうか？

```
 var
    www
      example.com
      yourtube.com
      headbook.com
```

Comment: 質問には linux タグがついていますが、OS に依存した話ではなく web サーバに関する話題かと思うので、想定している web サーバ (Apache や Nginx など) のタグを付けた方が、より役立つ質問になると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

一つの web サーバで複数のサイトを運用することを **バーチャルホスト** と呼びます。

ドキュメントルートもそれぞれのサイトごとに分ける必要がありますが、ドキュメントルート自体は外部に見えるわけではないので、管理しやすい任意の名前で構いません。

設定ファイルとの整合が取れていればいいので、想定されているようなドメイン名ごとに分ける例もありますし、単純にサイト名で分ける方法でも構いません。

参考までに、以下は Apache のドキュメントで示されているバーチャルホストの設定例 (抜粋) です。

[バーチャルホストの例 | Apache HTTP サーバ](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/vhosts/examples.html)

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example1
ServerName www.example.com

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /www/example2
ServerName www.example.org

# Other directives here

</VirtualHost>
```